# MySQL Date_Format and Filteering By Month/Year

Tags: mysql, date, date-format

Can anyone tell me what I'm done wrong? The following is returning an empty query when there should be results. I know it must be something to do with Date_Format and filtering by MONTH and YEAR... but I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

```
mysql_select_db($database_VALUATIONS, $VALUATIONS);
$query_valuations = sprintf("
    SELECT
        val_Trans_id,
        DATE_FORMAT(val_Date '%d-%m-%Y'),
        val_Company_Name,
        val_Company_Ref,
        val_Manufacturer,
        val_Model
    FROM valuations WHERE
        val_Company_Ref = %s AND MONTH(val_Date) =  %s AND
        YEAR(val_Date) =  %s
    ORDER BY
        val_Date DESC",
    GetSQLValueString($colname_valuations, "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($colname2_valuations, "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($colname3_valuations, "text")
);
```

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: the date format should be  DATE_FORMAT(val_Date,'%d-%m-%Y'). Its really hard to tell, without seeing your db table or knowing what you are trying to achieve. Hence, to help you please let us know what you want & the database tables along with it

Comment: if this helps any:

val_Date is a timestamp field

Trying to filter the data by month month and year with URL like:

www.domain.com?month=04&year=2014

Want to format the the date with mysql (rather than use PHP)

Comment: Solution is escaping the date format with an extra % like this:

DATE_FORMAT(val_Date '%%d-%%m-%%Y')

Everything works as it should then!!